# plumbing part for old jacuzzi tub

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

I have a jacuzzi tub that is at least 22 years old (I found it when I bought the house that long ago). I don't know the make and model, but I was told it is similar to a Jason J4260. To repair a leak, I had to remove the tub, and to do that I had to cut the "threaded flange" (if that is the correct name for it...) that keeps the water intake pipe attached to the tub (that is, the pipe that takes the water from the tub to the pump).

[[image: The part I am looking for before I cut it and removed it]]

I am now looking for that replacement part. The outer diameter of the threaded part is 3".

[[image: The part after I removed it]]

I have looked in just about all plumbing part stores in my area, and also did a lot of online search, but without results. So I have two specific questions:

1) What is the part called, so I can be more effective when I look for it?

2) Where can I find this part?

Thank you for any information.

As an update, I found a flange at guillens.com that "almost" works. It is made of plastic with a coarser thread than what I need. I am now looking for a similar part but made of metal and with finer thread to fit my pipe. I attach a photo that shows the broken metal flange I am trying to replace, and the plastic one I just got.

Another update: I have found a company that will custom manufacture that part but I now need to choose the material. They can only do it in aluminum or in steel (carbon steel and stainless steel). What is the right choice? (my guess is stainless steel).

[[image: The broken metal part and the plastic one that almost works]]

Comment: Have you asked Jacuzzi or a Jacuzzi dealer?  Http://www.jacuzzi.com

Comment: It isn't clear what we're looking at in the picture.  I don't see a threaded part.  But what's in the picture isn't a generic plumbing component that you can get at a hardware store.  It looks like an OEM part that you would need to get from Jacuzzi.

Comment: @Tyson No I have not asked Jacuzzi because I do not know for sure what the make is. I wrote "jacuzzi tub" to mean a generic tub with whirlpool (I guess it's like calling xerox any photocopying machine...). But I plan to call them tomorrow  just in case.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have added a second picture to show the part after I removed it.